# Clash of clans production rate

Tags: clash-of-clans

Is there a way to speed up production rate of buildings?

I know you can use gems, but what about by changing the time on device or something similar?

Comment: The buildings are on the game's server, not on your device, so the latter options would be impossible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, that would be considered cheating :P There is no way to increase the production rate of buildings other than using gems, or -in the case of gold mines and elixir collectors- by upgrading them so that their production rate per hour increases.

Comment: I think it would be a great feature if players could assign two or more builders to a building's construction to reduce the build time. Hopefully this will be added in future!